# Unable to deploy Firebase rules through Firebase CLI

Tags: javascript, android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having a Firebase rules File in `app/functions/index.js`
and I am trying to deploy the database rules through this Command:  `firebase deploy --only database` but when I am running this command it is giving this error :

> Error: There was an error loading firebase.json:
>
> Parse Error: functions/index.js is not of a supported config file type

This is my firebase.json file which is created when I have ran firebase init command

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "functions/index.js"
  }
}
```

and this is my index.js file

app/index.js

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
var count = 1;
exports.createNewUser = functions.auth.user().onCreate(event => {

    const user = event.data; // The Firebase user.

    const email = user.email || ''; // The email of the user.
    const displayName = user.displayName || '';
    const uid = user.uid || 'usersomething';
    const photo = user.photoUrl || '';

    console.log("the user" + uid);
    // The display name of the user.
    const userRef = admin.database().ref('/users');

    userRef.child(`${uid}`).update({
                  'email':email,
                  'photo':photo
                  });

    var date = new Date();
    var start_time = date.getTime();



});

exports.createEpisode = functions.database.ref('/users/{userId}/counsellor')
   .onWrite(event => {
     var uid = event.params.userId;
     const isACounsellor = event.data.val();
     if(isACounsellor == false){
     var episodeRef = admin.database().ref('/episodes');

     // create an episode for the user
     var newData = episodeRef.push();
     var date = new Date();
     var start_time = date.getTime();
     var episodeId = newData.key;
     newData.set(
                     {
                        'user':uid,
                         'goal':'',
                         'problem':'Anxiety',
                         'triggers':'',
                         'counsellor_uid':'',
                         'payment_id':'',
                         'pay':'',
                         'conversation_id':'',
                         'start_time':start_time,
                         'rating':'',
                         'review':'',
                         'paid':false,
                         'live_sessions':'1'
                     }
                         );
 var conversation = admin.database().ref('/conversation');

  // create a conversation

 var x = conversation.push();
 x.set(
     {
       'start_time':start_time,
       'end_time':''
     }
     );
 var y = x.child('messages').push().set({
   'message':"hey there!",
   'sender':'',
   'receive':uid,
   'timewrite':start_time
 });

  conversation.limitToLast(1).once('child_added',function(childSnapshot){
     var episodeReference = admin.database().ref('/episodes');
     var conversation_identifier = conversation.key | 'xyxy';

     episodeReference.child(episodeId).child('conversation_id').set(childSnapshot.key);
   });
 var userRef = admin.database().ref('/users');
   userRef.child(uid).child('episodes').child('0').set(episodeId);



 }
   });



exports.setTimeAndCounsellor = functions.database.ref('/episodes/{epId}/paid')
    .onWrite(event => {
      // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
      const original_value = event.data.val();
      if(original_value == true){
        var conversation = admin.database().ref('/conversation');
        var date = new Date();
        var start_time = date.getTime();
        var episodeReference = admin.database().ref('/episodes');
        var push_id = event.params.epId;
        episodeReference.child(push_id).once('value', function(snapshot){
            var type = snapshot.child('pay').val() | '';
            var conversation_id = snapshot.child('conversation_id').val();
            var d = new Date();
            if(type == 1){
              d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() + 1);
            }
            if(type == 2){
              d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() + 2);
            }
            if(type == 3){
              d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() + 3);
            }

            conversation.child(conversation_id).child('end_time').set(d.getTime());

        });
        episodeReference.on('child_added',function(childSnapshot){
          var userEpisodeKey = childSnapshot.key;
          var anEpisode = childSnapshot.val();
          var userOfEpisode = anEpisode['user'];

            if(count % 2 != 0){
                var counsellor_id = 'sqHdZojaTUTe26YtHTjQl32PPsq1';
                episodes.child(userEpisodeKey).child('counsellor_uid').set(counsellor_id);
              }else {
                var counsellor_id = 'KyruKVVpNsVZl5jByhCYXyLtcwK2';
                episodes.child(userEpisodeKey).child('counsellor_uid').set(counsellor_id);
            }

        });
      }
});




exports.addToConversation = functions.database.ref('episodes/{epId}/counsellor_uid')
    .onWrite(event => {
      const convo = admin.database().ref('/conversation');
      const episodes = admin.database().ref('/episodes');
      const cid = event.data.val();
      const epId = event.params.epId;
      episodes.child(epId).child('conversation_id').once("value",function(dataSnapshot){
      const convoId =  dataSnapshot.val();
      if(convoId !== ''){
        convo.child(convoId).child('messages').limitToFirst(1).once("child_added",function(dataSnapshot){
          const messageId = dataSnapshot.key;
          convo.child(convoId).child('messages').child(messageId).child('sender').set(cid);

        });

      }
      });
    }
    );

 exports.notifyCounsellor  = functions.database.ref('/episodes/{episodeId}/counsellor_uid')
  .onWrite(event =>{
  const value = event.data.val();
  var user_col = admin.database().ref('/users');
  user_col.child(value).child('episodes').child('0').set(episodeId);
}
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confusing two types of files that you can send to Firebase's servers with the CLI:

1. Firebase Database security rules define how the database server itself ensures that all read/write operations are valid and authorized. It is configured through a JSON file, typically called `rules.json` or `database-rules.json`. The [format of these security rules is documented here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/).
2. Cloud Functions for Firebase are JavaScript functions that run on Google's servers in response to events that occur in your Firebase project. The code is typically in a file called `index.js`. [Functions are documented here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/).

You are telling the Firebase CLI to deploy database security rules (option 1 above), but are passing it a file that defines Cloud Functions (option 2 above). Since the `functions/index.js` is not a valid JSON file, the tool fails to deploy it.

The first thing to do is to get remove that faulty `rules` definition from your `firebase.json`:

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database-rules.js"
  }
}
```

If you're trying to deploy only the Cloud Functions of your project, use `firebase deploy --only functions`.

If you're trying to deploy your database security rules, make sure you have a valid `database-rules.json` and run `firebase deploy --only database`.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the [Deployment](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#deployment) section of the Firebase CLI documentation as well as the [Firebase Web Codelab](https://github.com/firebase/friendlychat/tree/master/web) for an example of how the rules are formatted. The [firebase.json](https://github.com/firebase/friendlychat/blob/master/web/firebase.json) file specifies:

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database-rules.json"
  },
  ...
}
```

In that same directory, there is a [database-rules.json](https://github.com/firebase/friendlychat/blob/master/web/database-rules.json) file which contains the rules configuration that gets uploaded.

I am not 100% sure, but most likely the rules configuration file must be in JSON format, based on the error message you received: `Parse Error: functions/index.js is not of a supported config file type`.